# Last opened page is loading on pressing refresh button

Tags: javascript, html

I do not know JS/HTML and will try to describe the issue that I am facing.
I have a very basic html pages and some JS scripts for support.
I have several web pages that reflects some specific data and update that data every 15sec. But in case if I manually press the refresh button, instead of reloading the same page it is loading the last opened page that I opened.
Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks!!

Let me know what can be done for this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.